# Welcome on board vs Welcome aboard

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct for a pilot or airline cabin crew to say "welcome on board", rather than "welcome aboard?" Is there a difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**On board** describes that something is aboard a vessel, i.e., the location of something or someone.

> Onboard is one word (sometimes hyphenated—on-board) when it comes before the noun it modifies (e.g., onboard radio, onboard computer). Elsewhere, writers usually make on board two words.
> For instance, one might write, “We brought a radio on board so we could have an onboard radio.”   [Reference: "Onboard vs. on board", from grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/usage/onboard-on-board/)

It's rather an idiomatic phrase (or a quasi-adverb).

Examples:

- There are no medical physicians on board.
- Smoking is not allowed on board.

**Aboard** modifies an action and is often followed by reference of the vessel, e.g. to step aboard a something.

Grammarist supplies several examples (same reference as above):

> ## Examples
>
> **Onboard**
> *Justin boasts an onboard 3-D camera system for analyzing points in space. [[Wired News](https://www.wired.com/2011/05/robots-can-now-catch-balls/)]*
> *Although the airline grabs headlines for threatening to charge people to use onboard toilets or save money by dumping co-pilots, it normally turns to conventional ruses. [[Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2011/apr/19/ryanair-to-charge-seat-reservations-airline)]*
> *At one highway fill-up, the onboard computer showed I had a range of 880 km. [[National Post](https://nationalpost.com/news/road-test-2011-honda-odyssey-touring)]*
>
> **On board**
> *President John F. Kennedy called Shepard after he was taken on board the aircraft carrier that retrieved him from the ocean. [[USA Today](https://web.archive.org/web/20160105061710/http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/tech/science/space/2011-05-03-shepard-space-anniversary_n.htm)]*
> *San Pietro was being sailed by the remaining crew on board. [[Stuff.co.nz](http://www.stuff.co.nz/national/4921260/Police-make-arrest-on-protest-ship)]*

Comment: I like your answer, but didn't get the difference you explain between on board and aboard.

Answer (score 2):

"aboard" is only a contraction of "on board". May be pilots prefer "on board", but actually there is no difference between the two variants.

Comment: No, it's not a "contraction". The ***a-*** prefix occurs in many words *(abed, abreast, ashore, ajar, asleep, etc.)*.

Comment: Abed obviously derives from in bed.

Comment: It quite obviously does *not!* The ***a-*** prefix/preposition has been validly used in English for centuries with the general sense of *expressing position within, situation, etc.* The fact that you can in most contexts replace it with a *different* preposition doesn't mean the ***a-*** form is some kind of later derivation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. *Abed* is a 16th-century form, certainly used by Shakespeare, most famously in Henry V - *And gentlemen in England, now abed; Shall think themselves accursed they were not here*. It is also still used in Norfolk, or was when I was young. My parents always said *abed* for 'in bed'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It actually does. The _a-_ prefix is etymologically just a development of unstressed _of_, _in_, or _on_. I agree that they’re not contractions, but _aboard_ does come from _on board_, and _abed_ does come from _in bed_. The fact that the ‘full’ forms can still be used is just because both the noun and the preposition are still both part of the language and the collocation is literal and obvious enough to be remade productively. This isn’t always the case: _anew_ comes from _*of new_, which is less literal and has disappeared from the language.

Comment: @Janus: Granted, if we go back far enough the ***a-*** prefix did indeed derive from unstressed ***on*** (so in any case that leads to ***abed = on** bed*, not ***in** bed*). But it's hardly in the same league as saying *"**it's** is a contraction of **it is**"*, which is how I read this answer. Interestingly, OED says of ***aboard*** *Probably partly **a** prep.1 + **board** n., and partly Middle French **a bord** on a ship (1393 or earlier; French **à bord***. May be [sic! :] it's arguable either way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That’s why I said I agree they’re not contractions. They’re just forms whittled down by the hands of time until no longer recognisable, like so many other words. (Incidentally, OE _on_ and _in_ were often very poorly distinguished, since both were often reduced to just _a_, probably representing [ə]; whether _abed_ is originally from _on bed_ or _in bed_ is all but impossible to say now.)

Comment: @@Janus: Things get further complicated by the fact that you could make a case for saying ***onboard*** is a "contraction" of ***on board*** in many contexts today (***onboard** graphics*, for example). And there are many contexts *("Are you on board [with the plan]?")* where the single-word form is either unlikely or simply unacceptable. As my final contribution here, I'll just note that Google Books claims 4490 instances of *said "Welcome **aboard**!"*, but just 85 for the same quotated string with ***on board***.

Comment: From French "à bord" so, not a contraction.

Answer (score 2):

> We are on board the plane because we have boarded the aircraft.
>
> Aboard the ship, we watched the waves.

Perhaps a bit silly, but:

> As you are now on board, welcome aboard the our vessel.
>
> As you are now aboard (the vessel) let me say welcome on board!

I don't see any grammitical difference, rather it seems to be usage as Fumble (hi ya Fumble :) says. (And there's Amid ship - center of ship.)

It would be even more silly, but grammatically correct, to say:

> As you are now aboard, let me say welcome aboard.

I wonder if the word 'board' derives from the planks / boards used from dock to ship to enter the vessel?

"Arrr matey, Howard, walk the plank off board!"